# Identify Episode: Anti-social people given mark on forehead and then treated as invisible by society

Tags: story-identification

This is a TV episode from some story-of-the-week show made last century.  It is set in the near-ish future (there are hovering police drones) and the main character is a selfish lout.  His punishment is to be an outcast for a year.  A mark is made on his forehead and anyone seeing this mark is not allowed to acknowledge his existence.  At first he thinks that his will be wonderful, that he can act with impunity.   However, things don't go so well for him and he comes to appreciate his need for human interaction.  At the end of the year the mark is removed and he is welcomed back into society.

The kicker is at the end when he has his life back and is happy, when another outcast stumbles into him, begging for his help.  He sees the aching loneliness in her eyes and has to decide if whether his new-found empathy will move him to break the law and embrace her or should he look out for himself and ignore her as the law requires.

Comment: This sounds so much like a *Black Mirror* episode...

Comment: @FuzzyBoots the Black Mirror Christmas Special had something similar. The episode revolved around three different stories that resolved at the end to show that they were linked. The end part was that one the characters helped the police for a 'reduced' sentence. The 'reduced' sentence was that some techno lenses that everyone wore were switched so that everyone saw him as a red silhouette (which marked him as a sex offender) and he saw everyone as grey/white static silhouette's and voices were muffled, so everyone would avoid him and he couldn't hear or lip read anyone.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is "To see the invisible Man"
The second segment of the sixteenth episode from the first season (1985–86) of the television series The Twilight Zone.

[Quote from Wikipedia:-](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_See_the_Invisible_Man)

> Mitchell Chaplin lives in a world parallel to ours. A rude and obnoxious man, Chaplin has been found guilty of "coldness"—of not being friendly or open enough with those around him. According to the State, he is to be rendered "invisible" and a social outcast for one year. An implant placed on his forehead warns others not to interact with him in any way lest they be punished in a like manner

> Four months after completing his sentence, Chaplin is accosted in public by a young woman (whom he encountered during his term of invisibility) who wears the scar of an implant. Knowing the law, he initially ignores her but her cries move him to hug her. As they are surrounded by drones warning him to separate from her and move on, he declares that he can see the woman and that he cares about her suffering.

Based on a Robert Silverberg short story of the same name.
https://unfitmag.com/2019/04/27/to-see-the-invisible-man/

Comment: Thank you!   I remember the closing scene vividly and being very moved by the antinomy.