# Short story about a future society where criminals are punished by social isolation

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this story sometime in the '90s in an old magazine so it's certainly written no later than late '80s, probably even earlier.

I recall that it begins with the protagonist being punished for some crime by a person coming to his house and placing a mark on his face (I think it was on the forehead) that would mean the protagonist would be completely ignored by everyone who didn't have this mark, under the fear of being punished themselves. The punishment was supposed to last for a year.

I remember that at some point during this protagonist had appendicitis and had to find a doctor who would treat him. The story is mostly about him trying to survive this year and trying to force someone to interact with him.

Comment: Note, not a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/241326/identify-episode-anti-social-people-given-mark-on-forehead-and-then-treated-as/241328#241328 since one is about the TV adaptation of the story identified below.,

Comment: 8544-hour solitary confinement? gosh, that's _harsh_.

Comment: Can I pretty pretty please live in such a society and commit a crime there every year?

Comment: I don't know what would make you think about this story again now, in 2021 ;)

Comment: @RazarMackham - not everybody! He could associate with *other convicted criminals*. Sounds like a bad idea to me...

Comment: @Tim Oh, so it's like an Outcast Island kind of thing? That _is_ dangerous (potentially) :O

Comment: @Tim In the story it's clear that he can not associate with other convicted criminals for fear of further punishment.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Pretty sure this is *[To See the Invisible Man](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?59335)* by Robert Silverberg. The story was first published in [the April 1963 issue](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?62299) of *Worlds of Tomorrow*, and later reprinted in numerous other publications, including several in the 1980s and '90s.

[This review](https://featuredfutures.wordpress.com/2019/01/15/robert-silverbergs-to-see-the-invisible-man-and-hawksbill-station/) offers a good description of the plot, noting that the protagonist is subjected to an unusual form of punishment, whereby he's marked with a brand on his forehead which compels everyone else to ignore him for a year, lest they be punished the same way:

> “To See the Invisible Man” is clearly not action-oriented pulp, but is a dark tale of alienation and of a form of reconciliation or enlightenment. **The protagonist has been “cold” to society, not sympathizing with his fellow man. This isn’t an offense that receives jail time, but the “lesser” sentence of being made Invisible for a year. A temporary brand is placed on the perpetrator’s forehead and anyone who acknowledges his existence will be made Invisible, themselves.** The story follows the man’s testing of the limits, experiencing quickly palling cheap thrills, and moving through more painful, fearful, and depressing experiences as he adjusts to his condition. Finally, he is released from his sentence as a changed man, but his change is not without irony.

In the 1980s, the story was adapted into [an episode of *The Twilight Zone*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_See_the_Invisible_Man).

Comment: This is the exact story I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Oh man, this is great. I was so sure that this theme was a Sturgeon short story that i searched all over. It's also good because I prefer Robert Silverberg.

Comment: While it probably shouldn't be, the [text of the story can be found on Unfit Magazine](https://unfitmag.com/2019/04/27/to-see-the-invisible-man/).